# Bash directory alias/redirect

Tags: bash, redirect, scripting, directory, alias

I'm trying to compile a library and his dependencies (lots of dependencies), but the system that I'm using didn't have the usual directory structure. I'm searching for a method to "redirect" all the scripts callings to, for example, `/bin/sh` to `/foo/bar/sh`.

Is something like this possible?

EDIT:

I forgot to tell that / is read-only, so i can't make a /bin directory containing symbolic links pointing to the actual bin directory

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbolic links.

```
ln -s /foo/bar/sh /bin/sh
```

First, you'll have to remove the original /bin/sh. But make sure you don't use the /bin/sh at the moment you launch the rm (or mv), otherwise you may get yourself locked. The best change your shell to /foo/bar/sh first and try to login while you still have original shell running so you can fix possible issues.

Comment: I forgot to tell that i already tried this, but / is read-only, so i can't...

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `$PATH` variable.

`export PATH=/foo/bar:$PATH <command>`

In this way you will load binaries before from `/foo/bar` than `/bin`.